# Android Studio: Can't find the emulator executable

Tags: java, android, android-studio

cannot run any app on emulator. When I click on the `run-app`, it instantly shows notifications `ERROR: can't find the emulator executable` and `process finished with code-1`.

Comment: Did you install the emulator using the sdk manager?

Comment: yes it is installed.

Answer (score 5):

I have same problem, my antivirus (AVG) delete exe of emulator at path:

***C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe***

If the problem is your antivirus you can follow this step:

- Open your antivirus
- Went into the Quarantine section
- Restore exe file.

[image: AVG Quarantine]

Next time that you try to run emulator, disable your antivirus.

*If the problem does not concern the antivirus, I advise you to uninstall and reinstall the emulator.*

Bye